# multiple column update from other tables column in single query - performance improvement

Tags: oracle, performance

I Have a table MAIN_TABLE of 6 million records. Below query is taking 4 hours. Can someone suggest performance improvement

MAIN_TABLE structure. 
FIELD1 (NUMBER), FIELD2(VARCHAR), FILED3............

```
UPDATE MAIN_TABLE MT
SET
 FIELD3 = (SELECT FLDA FROM TABLE1 where FLDX= MT.FIELD2 AND FLDZ='XYZ'),
 FIELD4 = (SELECT FLDB FROM TABLE1 where FLDX= MT.FIELD2 AND FLDZ='PQR'), 
 FIELD6 = (SELECT FLDD FROM TABLE1 where FLDX= MT.FIELD2 AND FLDW='FGH');
```

Will looping help? Will dividing the population into multiple threads help?
Will any DB hint work?

Comment: A few questions. Are you seriously updating the same field (FIELD4) TWICE in the same UPDATE statement? Why? Then, what do you mean by FIELD2 is part of the "may field"? What does that mean? Do you mean "part of the primary key"? Is it that difficult to use the correct terms? Then, please learn how to format your code, it's REALLY easy, it just requires a little bit of effort on your part. (I did it for you now.) You won't get much help from volunteers if you don't put a little bit of effort in it yourself.

Comment: Be sure of your code ..  you have also 3 times  TABLE1 and one TABLE2  .. are you sure .?  couldb that in yoru case are better 4 different update  instead of 6millions of subquery  potentially  ( just one for each row match your where )

Comment: I am not updating FIELD2 twice. That was typo. Yes, I have used TABLE1 thrice and TABLE2 once. 
I am thinking if parallel hint can help me here?

Comment: Why don't you try splitting it into two different updates?: one for the three columns that reference `table1` and the other for `table2`

Comment: Ok i can do that.UPDATE MAIN_TABLE MT
SET
 FIELD3 = (SELECT FLDA FROM TABLE1 where FLDX= MT.FIELD2 AND FLDZ='XYZ'),
 FIELD4 = (SELECT FLDB FROM TABLE1 where FLDX= MT.FIELD2 AND FLDZ='PQR'),
 FIELD6 = (SELECT FLDD FROM TABLE1 where FLDX= MT.FIELD2 AND FLDW='FGH');.     But still it is taking time